# FuncAnimation problems with using dates on X ax

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a movie of precipitation by date by a moving bar. It works fine with a float or integer ('JD') on x ax, but not with dates('DateTime') (lines 38/39, 45/46, 52/53). What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML
import datetime
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

#import waterlevel data and locations
dateparse = lambda xd: [pd.datetime.strptime(daa, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') for daa in xd]
WL = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['DateTime'], date_parser=dateparse, dayfirst=True)
#WL = pd.DataFrame(waterlevels)

#precipitation
maxPH = 10 #round(float(np.max(PH)),3)
minPH = 1#round(float(np.min(PH)),3)

#data for movie with varying frames
aframes = (len(WL.loc[:,'DateTime'])) - 1
print ('Amount of waterlevel measurement points: ', aframes)
print ('Measurements from ', WL.loc[0,['DateTime']], 'to', WL.loc[aframes,['DateTime']])

"""MOVIE .AVI for varying precipitation """
#set up figure, the axes and the plot element to animate
fig, (ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1,figsize=(15,15),sharey=False,sharex=False)
#title and subgraph information
ax2.grid()
#precipiation
ax2.plot(WL.loc[:,['DateTime']],WL.loc[:,['regen [mm]']], linewidth = 0.5, c ='blue', label = 'Rain per hour')
#ax2.plot(WL.loc[:,['JD']],WL.loc[:,['regen [mm]']], linewidth = 0.5, c ='blue', label = 'Rain per hour')

#setup waterlevel frames
line, = ax2.plot([],[], c = 'red', lw=5) 

def init():
    xprec = WL.loc[0,['DateTime','DateTime']]
    #xprec = WL.loc[0,['JD','JD']]
    yprec = WL.loc[0,['phmin','phmax']]
    line.set_data(xprec,yprec)
    return line3

def animate(i):
        xprec = WL.loc[i,['DateTime','DateTime']]
        #xprec = WL.loc[i,['JD','JD']]
        yprec = WL.loc[i,['phmin','phmax']]
        line.set_data(xprec,yprec)
        return line

# call the animator. blit=True means: only re-daw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = (aframes + 1), init_func = init)
#aframes must be aframes!!!!!!

anim.save('testmov_precipitation2.mp4', fps=20, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
plt.show()
```

The contents of the csv file:

DateTime,Date2,Time,regen [mm],phmin,phmax,JD
10/01/2017 01:00,10/01/2017,01:00,1,1,10,1
10/01/2017 02:00,10/01/2017,02:00,2,1,10,2
10/01/2017 03:00,10/01/2017,03:00,4,1,10,3
10/01/2017 04:00,10/01/2017,04:00,6,1,10,4
10/01/2017 05:00,10/01/2017,05:00,1,1,10,5
10/01/2017 06:00,10/01/2017,06:00,3,1,10,6
10/01/2017 07:00,10/01/2017,07:00,8,1,10,7
10/01/2017 08:00,10/01/2017,08:00,9,1,10,8
10/01/2017 09:00,10/01/2017,09:00,10,1,10,9
10/01/2017 10:00,10/01/2017,10:00,2,1,10,10
10/01/2017 11:00,10/01/2017,11:00,5,1,10,11
10/01/2017 12:00,10/01/2017,12:00,8,1,10,12
10/01/2017 13:00,10/01/2017,13:00,1,1,10,13
10/01/2017 14:00,10/01/2017,14:00,2,1,10,14
10/01/2017 15:00,10/01/2017,15:00,3,1,10,15
10/01/2017 16:00,10/01/2017,16:00,4,1,10,16
10/01/2017 17:00,10/01/2017,17:00,5,1,10,17
10/01/2017 18:00,10/01/2017,18:00,8,1,10,18
10/01/2017 19:00,10/01/2017,19:00,7,1,10,19

Comment: "but it doesn't work with dates" is not a sufficient problem description. What is wrong? Is there an error? (If so incluce tranceback) Or is the resulting plot not what you expect? (In this case describe what you get and what you'd expect instead).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No error occurs. The result is not what I expected. The idea is getting a graph with a moving bar on the xaxis, in avi, representing the data, so that you can see how much precipitation was measured. The moving bar works perfectly by using numbers (column JD), but not with the dates (columns DateTime or Date2). I hope it is clear what I mean?